# Integration by substitution, but from sphere to sphere

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, field-theory

Suppose we have a smooth injection $\Phi(x,y)$ from an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to $S = \Phi(\Omega) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. It is well-known that the **integration by substitution** formula holds:

$$
\int_{S} f(x,y,z) \, \text{d}\sigma(x,y,z) = \int_{\Omega} f(\Phi(x,y)) \, J(x,y) \, \text{d}x \, \text{d}y
$$

where $J(x,y)$ denotes the Jacobian.

Recently, I have been working on projects related to integration on a sphere. For example, consider a smooth bijection $\Phi(\omega)$ from $S^2$ to $S^2$, the sphere in 3-dimensional space. I am curious if there exists a formula like:

$$
\int_{S^2} f(\omega) \, \text{d}\sigma(\omega) = \int_{S^2} f(\Phi(\omega)) \, T(\omega) \, \text{d}\omega
$$

where $T(\omega)$ is only determined by the transition function $\Phi$.

I tried to use the Jacobian, but it is evidently incorrect because $T$ is **not even differentiable** on the sphere in 3-dimensional space (it is only defined on the sphere!).

I read some papers and found something like:

$$
\int_{S^2} f(\omega) \, \text{d}\sigma(\omega) = \int_{S^2} f(\Phi(\omega)) \, ||DT_\omega(\vec s)\times DT_\omega(\vec t)|| \, \text{d}\omega
$$

where(copied from paper):

> $\vec s$ and $\vec t$ are orthonormal tangent vectors of the unit
> sphere at $\omega$ and the $DT_{\omega}$ is the 'differential' of $T$
> with respect to the vector $\omega$, The norm of the cross product of
> transformed tangent vectors accounts for the distortion in the
> integration domain, similar to the Jacobian determinant for a change
> of variables in ambient space.

But it doesn't provide any precise definition. I don't know how to define the 'differential' of $T$ w.r.t. $\omega$.

I would be more than grateful if you could provide any clues, thank you!

---

Update:

I found something like:

$$\int_\mathcal{S^2}{f(\omega)}\text d\sigma(\omega)=\int_\mathcal{S^2}{f(\Phi(\omega))\frac{|\omega^TJ^*(\omega)F(\omega)|}{|F(\omega)|^3}}\text d\sigma(\omega)$$

where $\Phi((x,y,z)^T)=\frac{F((x,y,z)^T)}{|F((x,y,z)^T)|}$, $\Phi$ is bijection from sphere to sphere, $F$ is smooth and non-zero on the sphere.$J$ denotes the Jacobian of $F$ and $J^*$ is the adjugate matrix.

Comment: Does your smooth bijection have smooth inverse?

Comment: In particular, how much differential topology if any do you know? The answer to your question in general is yes, but the Jacobian will depend on your choice of coordinates on $S^2$.

Comment: @Chris you can assume the inverse is smooth. So what will happen if the inverse is not smooth?

Comment: If this inverse is not smooth, then the statement is false. This whole question basically boils down to the (orientable) diffeomorphism invariance of integration